# Meteor.js MongoDB access?

Tags: macos, mongodb, meteor

I am new to Mongo and Meteor.

I have installed Meteor on Mac OSX 10.8, and I have created a new Meteor app using a collection called 'Fillup'.

I am going through some tutorials about Mongo, and I am trying to learn the shell commands, but none of them are working.

I want to use Mongo command line to view and manipulate the collection I have going in my Meteor app.

I installed Mongo seperately after Meteor, and I think Meteor might me using a different 'copy' of Mongo, because now when I try 'mongo' I get :

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test
Sun Jul 28 14:25:33.055 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed
```

Whether Meteor is running or not, and Meteor works fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Meteor is using different binaries of Mongo to keep the compatible version.

If you want to test your Mongo shell commands or just play with it on the same version as Meteor, create a Meteor app and keep it running:

```
meteor create testapp
cd testapp
meteor
```

And in different shell (or tab) run

```
meteor mongo
```

The reason why it didn’t work in your case: you didn’t start the MongoDB server command `mongod`. But when you run your Mongo app locally, it will run `mongod` with the correct set of flags and separate database file.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `mongod` first and then `mongo`.

> To start MongoDB using all defaults, issue the following command at the system shell:
>
> mongod

This is for vanilla MongoDB though, you might be using a Meteor-specific flavor like someone else mentioned.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

Comment: Thanks, yes, my suspicion was correct after-all,  Meteor runs its own copy of MongoDB.